# Angular Momentum Operators generates rotation transformations - Stern-Gerlach device explanation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, rotation, determinism

In a lecture we were taught how the angular momentum operator $\vec{L}$ acts as the generator of rotations in quantum mechanics, which are defined using the following equation:

$R_u(\alpha)=\hat{1}-(i/\hbar) \alpha\vec{L}\vec{u}$

Where $u$ is the rotational axis direction and $\alpha$ is the angle of rotation.

I thought maybe this could be related to the Stern-Gerlach experiment, where if you are to measure the angular momentum of a particle in a given direction (z, for example), the result will always be in the +z or -z direction. That is, the machine both measures and determines (by limiting the options to two possible values) what the angular momentum will be.

Is this related to the concept of angular momentum generating rotations, given that only certain values will result from a Stern-Gerlach machine and so only certain rotations are allowed?

I am looking for an intuitive explanation relating the two concepts, if there is one that is.